# Installments Payment for WooCommerce Subscription

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using **WooCommerce Subscription** plugin for taking recurring payments. It's taking recurring payments for the lifetime or till subscription expires.

Currently, it looks like:[image: Recurring Subscription Payment]

But I don't want to take payment for the lifetime. I want to take payment as installments and subscription will stay forever if user pay all installments.

Suppose, I want to take payment for 6 consucative months. If user paid all 6 installments, subscription of that product never ends.

Backend will something look like this:[image: Installment Payments]

So, can you guys help me about that?
Thanks in advance.